# how to get selected value from listview

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

I want to select finance Name and after clicked finance Name i want to get code of same finance. The finance Name is listed into listview.

My Firebase database structure is below:
 [image]

```
financeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            //Map<String, Object> data = (Map<String, Object>) snapshot.getValue();
            String value = new Gson().toJson(snapshot.getValue());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(value));
            f = object.getString("Finance Name");
            name = snapshot.getKey();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


            financeName.add(f);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(FinanceNameListActivity.this, CodeAndNameActivity.class);
                String abc = (String) ((TextView) view).getText();
                intent.putExtra("Name",abc);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get response from firebase and set it to model call or hashmap or array up to you then implement interface for list view click event or simple click event with get position and get value from where you set firebase response.

Comment: from the     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)                                                                                                      i can get same finance Name but i can't get code i don't know how to check from same finance name.

Comment: Set finance code in array like you set finance name.Get finance code for same position like finance name.

Comment: i don't want to show the code of finance if some one clicked finance name then in next page i want to put same code in put extra and compare if(code.equals(editextcode)) and the verification process going to successful.

Comment: financeName.add(f);financecode.add(your param name);
            intent.putExtra("Name",abc);intent.putExtra("code",financecode.get(postion)):
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });